# Retrieve data from coredata table to an UIPickerView (inside a textField)

Tags: core-data, nsmutablearray, uipickerview, nsfetchrequest

I want to retrieve a list of types from a "table" from my Main.xcdatamodeld (coredata) to put in a UIPickerView. This entity "Type" has only one attribute "name" (string).

If I put some strings in the NSMutableArray it works perfectly. The UIPickerView shows the strings. Above is the simple NSMutableArray.

```
resultFetch = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Electronics",@"School",@"Kitchen",@"Office", nil];
```

But when I do a fetch from the coredata I get an error. Here's the code below.

AddItemViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

nameField.text = [self.currentItem name];
locationField.text = [self.currentItem location];
//typeField.text = [self.currentItem type];
quantityField.text = [[self.currentItem quantity] stringValue];

self.nameField.delegate = self;
self.locationField.delegate = self;
//self.typeField.delegate = self;
self.quantityField.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"ViewDidload before put fetch in array");
//Put fetch in NSArray resultFetch

AppDelegate *myApp = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

resultFetch = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Type" inManagedObjectContext:[myApp managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[myApp managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (Type *t in fetchedObjects) {

    [resultFetch addObject:t];
    NSLog(@"resultFetch: %@", resultFetch);

}

//Define typePicker
typePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,43,320,480)];
typePicker.delegate = self;
typePicker.dataSource = self;
[typePicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
typeField.inputView = typePicker;

//Create done button in UIPickerView
myPickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];
myPickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[myPickerToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];
[myPickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
typeField.inputAccessoryView = myPickerToolbar;
 NSLog(@"End ViewDidLoad");

}

-(void)pickerDoneClicked
{
NSLog(@"Done Clicked");

[typeField resignFirstResponder];
myPickerToolbar.hidden=YES;
typePicker.hidden=YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [resultFetch count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [resultFetch objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
typeField.text = [resultFetch objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

The error is:

2013-11-14 10:31:53.099 Storage[1226:70b] ViewDidload before put fetch in array

2013-11-14 10:31:53.102 Storage[1226:70b] resultFetch: (
    " (entity: Type; id: 0x8a83e50  ; data: )"
)

2013-11-14 10:31:53.103 Storage[1226:70b] resultFetch: (
    " (entity: Type; id: 0x8a83e50  ; data: )",
    " (entity: Type; id: 0x8a6ae80  ; data: )"
)

2013-11-14 10:31:53.104 Storage[1226:70b] resultFetch: (
    " (entity: Type; id: 0x8a83e50  ; data: )",
    " (entity: Type; id: 0x8a6ae80  ; data: )",
    " (entity: Type; id: 0x8aa9650  ; data: )"
)

2013-11-14 10:31:53.107 Storage[1226:70b] End ViewDidLoad

2013-11-14 10:31:57.148 Storage[1226:70b] -[Type length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8aa08e0

It doesn't show the Type names that are inside the database.
Can you help me fetching this "table" properly to put those attribute strings inside a UIPickerView? All I want is a pretty NSMutableArray I can use! :)

Thank you very much for your help.

Paula

Comment: Where are you using 'type.length'? That's the reason the app crashes. You are accessing your managed object 'Type' but that object has no property/method called 'length'. You probably need to replace 'type.length' by 'resultFetch.count', assuming you need the number of fetched objects.

Comment: Also you can replace NSLog(@"resultFetch: %@", resultFetch); by NSLog(@"resultFetch: %@", t.name); to log the actual string values.

Comment: Hi Leijonien. I changed the NSLog and now I can see the Type values. I can´t see anything in my code with the word lenght in it! :/

Comment: And I don't get it why if I change the fetch to a simple array it works fine!!! Grrrrrrrrr :(

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint to check where it actually crashes?

Comment: and look for the word 'length' (not 'lenght')

Comment: If I change:
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Type" inManagedObjectContext:[myApp managedObjectContext]];

to:
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:[myApp managedObjectContext]];
I get the same error but with Item instead of Type!

2013-11-14 16:49:26.240 Storage[2457:70b] -[Item length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8acecb0

So the problem is in the fetch part!

Comment: I added an All Exceptions breakpoint. But when it crashes points to main.m. I'll put some breakpoints and try to find the spot! :)

Comment: The problem is in here:
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

    return [resultFetch objectAtIndex:row];

}

Comment: when I put a  NSLog(@"titleForRow %@", [resultFetch objectAtIndex:row]); before the return, I get this

2013-11-14 17:06:11.414 Storage[2586:70b] titleForRow <Type: 0x8bc64a0> (entity: Type; id: 0x8bb3700 <x-coredata://68C302CC-8D03-4FF8-B03B-85CDDB12A4BF/Type/p1> ; data: {
    items = "<relationship fault: 0x8be77c0 'items'>";
    name = "one type";
})
2013-11-14 17:06:11.415 Storage[2586:70b] -[Type length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bc64a0

It's normal? :/

Comment: Leijonien, I got it! It's stupid! :)
I changed the line [resultFetch addObject:t]; to [resultFetch addObject:t.name];!
Dah! Now it's so clear! Thank you for your company through the problem! :)

Comment: You're welcome, i'm glad you solved it!

Comment: Final note: I see you updated the original question including the code. It's a better practice to put the solution in an answer (and accept it) rather than updating/mixing the original question with your answer.

Comment: Done it! I can only accept my own answer in 2 days! :) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! Changed the line inside for statement from [resultFetch addObject:t]; to [resultFetch addObject:t.name];.
Seems it was too much garbage! :)